# Video no longer playing in iOS 8 WebbApp standalone mode, anyone found a solution?

Tags: ios, video, safari, iphone-standalone-web-app, ios-standalone-mode

**This bug looks to be resolved as of iOS 9.**

---

The video plays fine on the desktop evergreen browsers, and in stand alone mode on Android devices.

It even plays nice on the iOS8 safari, but once a user goes and adds it to their home screen, the video no longer plays.

I put up an example here http://bugs.readingplus.com/ios8-video-test/.

If you using iOS8 you can play the video, add the url to your home screen and load it up. You will get the controls, but once you touch play all you get is the first frame.

I put the [source of the page on Github](https://github.com/ishmaelAhmed/ios8-video-test), or you can just go to the page and view the source.

Am I missing something, is my markup fubared, is this just a bug, has anyone found a work around?

---

As of iOS 8.3 the issue is partially resolved. I have verified that the video, in the example, now plays when launched from the "Add to Home Screen" link.

The remaining issue is the audio, it is not being rendered/played.

Comment: I received verification on **9/26/14** that this is a known bug in **iOS 8.0**.

Comment: any link to the official bug release?

Comment: @ishmael.ahmed Can you please give us link to the official bug release?

Comment: Apple doesn't link publicly to their internal bug list.

Comment: @AlexG I created a bug report for this and Apple closed it as a duplicate. The original is still currently open, as of this response. I would suggest creating one via https://bugreport.apple.com/, it should give it higher visibility.  I have the internal # if you really want it, but have not yet seen any public verification.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like iOS 8.3 fixes this issue. I have a standalone web app that uses an audio element, and it's working as expected now. FINALLY!

Comment: Is the audio being played with the video?  It is not in the example I gave in the question.  I was wondering what format is your video in?

Answer (score 0):

this is great news, can it be confirmed by others?
I don't want to take the plunge and update to 8.3 until I'm confident video and audio in a homescreen webclip are working in iOS 8.3